# In Chinese culture is it good luck to let facial mole hair grow long?

Tags: hair

Walking through Chinatown, I occasionally notice men whose faces appear shaved except for a collection of uncut hairs sprouting from a facial mole. I don't know what came over me today, but I decided to Google this phenomenon, and I stumbled upon [a blog post at a site called "Ask A Chinese <del>Guy</del> Girl"](http://ask-a-chinese-guy.blogspot.com/2010/07/what-is-it-with-hairy-moles-people-in.html).

> Moles in Chinese society are something to do with luck, it is much like the superstition of Cantonese people around Chinese New year, the lack of 4th floors or any other floor with a number 4 in it. Moles too can determine, luck and life. Thus if you have an unlucky mole on your face you get it removed. If you have a lucky one then you don't remove it simple as, and you especially leave it alone.

The author includes a graphic of lucky and unlucky moles:

[image: Lucky and unlucky moles in Chinese culture]

Also included is a full index explaining each mole's significance. For instance, a mole at location 21 correlates with:

> Tend to have foot problems. Need to prevent water-related accidents.

Where does this mole map come from? Is it authentic? What's really up with the cultural practice of letting mole hair grow long?